# How do I substract 60 seconds from a time in angular

Tags: angularjs, time, subtraction

I would like to create a function that allows me to substract 60 seconds from the current time, and then 60 seconds from that new adjusted time and so on.

Started like this but now I'm stuck...

angular:

```
 var t = new Date();  
 t.setSeconds(t.getSeconds() - 60); 
 $scope.newt  = t;  
 $scope.newt = $filter('date')(t, "HH:mm");


 $scope.oneminuteless = function() {    
     ??? 
 };
```

HMTL:

```
<div>Time {{t}} | New Time: {{newt}}</div>  
<button ng-click="oneminuteless()"><i class="icon icon-chevron-left"></i></button>
```

I don't know how to substract from the adjusted time so it goes back in time as long as you click the button, it always keeps using the current time.

Thanks!

Comment: You'll probably want to use MomentJS, here's an [angular directive](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment) for it. Then you can do stuff like `moment(t).subtract(60, 'seconds')`

Comment: thanks for the tip. moment is working but how do I loop through the generated times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to achieve, you could do the following:

Controller:

```
$scope.t = new Date();
$scope.newt = new Date($scope.t.getTime() - 60000);

$scope.oneminuteless = function(){
    $scope.newt = new Date($scope.newt.getTime() - 60000);
}
```

Your HTML:

```
<div>Time {{t | date: 'HH:mm'}} | New Time: {{newt | date: 'HH:mm'}}</div>
```

Use angular filter date to show only hours and minutes

`getTime()` will return the number of milliseconds since 1970/01/01.

Working sample
https://plnkr.co/edit/2TtLRoVro4ccidxWznlz?p=preview